# How to pass input as a string in angular

Tags: angular

```
    <page [pagetitle]="pagePath">  

<content>
    <section title="Landlords" [isExpanded]="sectionExpansionStatus[0].isExpanded" (onSectionExpandChange)="onSectionExpandChange($event)">
        <landlord-list [categorytype]=1 *ngIf="sectionExpansionStatus[0].isExpanded"></landlord-list>
    </section>
    <section title="Tenants" [isExpanded]="sectionExpansionStatus[1].isExpanded" (onSectionExpandChange)="onSectionExpandChange($event)">
        <landlord-list [categorytype]=2 *ngIf="sectionExpansionStatus[1].isExpanded"></landlord-list>
    </section>
    <section title="Additional Data Field">
        <additional-datafields [addlDataFieldCategoryId]="30"></additional-datafields>
    </section>       
</content>
```

I can access this 'categorytype' from my component like this.

```
      if (contextObj.categorytype == 1)
        {
            //write code here

        }
```

If I want to pass categorytype as string.. how can I do that? How can I access from the component?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass that field as string there are a couple of ways like:

```
var strCategory = contextObj.categorytype + "";
var strCategory = String(contextObj.categorytype);
var strCategory = contextObj.categorytype.toString()
```

And by access from component:

Use `@ViewChild` to access some element in the view.

Use `[attr.src]` to creating binding to 'src' attribute of an element.

Use `Renderer` if for some reason you need to change the DOM imperatively.

Comment: mmmm how about contextObj.category.toString() that is much easier than declaring the variable two times to converted to string.

Comment: @btinoco thanks for reminding, however the point was to show the conversion not the declaration

Answer (score 0):

You can test categorytype as a string like this...

```
  if (contextObj.categorytype.toString() === "1")
    {
        //write code here

    }
```

or pass it in your component like this

```
 <div [categorytype]="1"></div>
```

make sure you declare categorytype as a string inside your component if using typings.